# Why was this flag on a post that doesn't answer the question disputed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging, answers, answer-quality

I have recently flagged this [post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70499/was-the-rebellion-of-the-north-really-necessary/148354#148354) as *not an answer*.

While it does feature clear reasoning and fair amount of knowledge, I was unable to detect an answer to the original question.

Why was my flag disputed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your flag was disputed because the answer directly addresses the question asked, noting that the one of the key reasons for the rebellion was to secure vengeance for the death of Eddard Stark.

Comment: The answer briefly alludes to the reason behind the rebellion, but proceeds in another direction entirely. Thus, it seems as an answer to *another* question, namely `Why did the rebellion fail?`

Comment: Fair enough then. Since it briefly alludes to it, that makes it an answer.

Comment: My point is, if an answer doesn't mainly address the original question, should we still allow it?

Comment: @Gallifreian - Yes. The general rule of thumb is that if any portion of the answer addresses the question, that it's an answer.

Comment: Ok then, I'll be even more moderate with flags. *Dear diary. Seven days have passed since my last VTC flag. My hands are starting to shake*

Comment: @Gallifreian - I once went a whole day without using a dupe vote. Then I passed out.